# Deserializing an ArrayList

Tags: java, session, serialization, arraylist, deserialization

I am having trouble deserializing an object from a file in Java in a new session.

I can serialize an arraylist to file, and then deserialize it in the same session, however, if I create a new Main object and try to deserialize the same file that worked in the previous session, the code does not work.

Why would this be?

Here is my code:

```
public void LoadPersonListFromFile(String Filename)
{
  try
  {
     PersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();          
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(Filename));
     ArrayList<Person> PersonList = (ArrayList<Person>) in.readObject();
     in.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public void SavePersonFileToFile(String Filename)
{
  try
  {
     ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Filename));
     out.writeObject(PersonList);
     out.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

The DeSerialization seems to be working, because if I do a .size() call on the List in the LoadPersonListFromFile method, I get the value of 2. However, if I call the .size() method on the List outside of the LoadPersonListFromFile method, the .size() is shown as 0. Why would this be? Do I need to copy the deserialized ArrayList into the private field?

I have the following private field to store the ArrayList at the top of the class:

```
private ArrayList<Person> PersonList;
```

**EDIT2**

Got it working. Here is the code:

```
public void LoadPersonListFromFile(String Filename)
{
  try
  {
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(Filename));
     ArrayList<Person> PersonListFromFile = (ArrayList<Person>) in.readObject();
     in.close();
     PersonList = PersonListFromFile;       
    }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the exception if any?

Comment: What is the problem with the above code? Seems all right.

Comment: Does you `Person` class implement `Serializable`?

Comment: does it throw "InvalidClassException"??

Comment: No exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you didn't define a static final long `serialVersionUID` in `Person` class. Basically, when you compile a `Serializable` class that has no `serialVersionUID` defined in the source code, the Java compiler will define it for you with random value.

To solve the issue, define the following in `Person` class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```